# RadioGroup is not updated to the selected radio button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So i want to create a dynamic Radio Group (using material ui) witch takes an object as parameter and build the radio buttons using this object. it works fine (when i click on the radio button the state changes) but the problem is when i click on the radio button it doesn't get updated (selected). 
can any one help me please ?

 you can find a demo in codesandbox. 
In the demo there is two examples :

1. the first one uses the material ui RadioGroup component and it
   works fine
2. the second uses my new component named RadioBox and what it doesn't work

https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-sea-rrx2u?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem :

Value of Male and female key is 0 and 1 respectively in integer but props.value on `RadioBox.js` value comes on string.

One of the Solution:

add parseInt on value attribute on `RadioBox` component return value.

```
return (
    <RadioGroup value={parseInt(props.value)} onChange={props.handleChange}>
      {radioBox}
    </RadioGroup>
  );
```

Comment: after testing ti works fine. thanks a lot saurssaurav you saved my day. the value passed to the RadioBox was a string and not an integer you are right.